# RewriteRule and Parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

i would like to send a GET on my Index.php

Thats the htacces

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login  index.php?login [NC,L]
```

the php

```
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
   include 'Login.php';
}
```

and on the html is

```
<input name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET["email"] ?>"/>
```

how i can send now the GET'email' on the login.php?
I would like to

```
localhost/login?email=test.test@gmail.com&moreparameters=test1
```

thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `QSA` flag for that purpose :

```
RewriteRule ^login  index.php?login [NC,L,QSA]
```

By the way, you have XSS in your php:

```
<input name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["email"]); ?>"/>
```